# How to refer selected image on client side with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the HTML source code for a selected image file on client side:

We need to retrieve the image for further processing. We tried

```
var f = $(this).file[0]
var f = $('#uploaded_file_file_for_upload').file[0]
```

In both cases, there is error of `f` not `defined`.

getElementById works but what it returns is not the image object:

```
var f = document.getByElementId('uploaded_file_file_for_upload')
```

What's the right way to retrieve the image selected in jquery?

Comment: [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can look at this source :
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications

considering this html:

```
 <input type="file" id="upload_file_file_for_upload">
```

we can use jquery to get the file:

```
var f= $('#upload_file_file_for_upload')[0].files[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to grab the id, try

```
 var f = $('#upload_file_file_for_upload')
```

Comment: Need to grab the image object